# Android Content view not yet created fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, error-handling, compiler-errors, fragment

Currently I have a tab layout setup with 4 fragments. I have one fragment which originally I was getting a duplicate id error which occured when switching between the fragments. I managed to resolve the issue by apply the following code below, but now I get a content view not yet created message when switching.

```
public class contactus2 extends Fragment {

private static View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }
    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactus2, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        Log.i("Inflate", "View Hidden");

    }
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please provide the actual android errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreateView()` should never reference a static View object.  Android will tear down and reconstruct the fragment's view when cycling through the application.  Because of this, you should always be inflating a new view inside of onCreateView.  The way you have it now, your app will attempt to reuse a view for multiple fragments.

Something like this:

```
public class contactus2 extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactus2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Basically, remove the static assignment to your fragment's view reference.